# Write a library for Mutex protected variables in Go

Tags: go, library

## Problem description

I'm trying to write a library for protecting variables from concurrent access using sync.RWMutex. The goal is to prevent accidental misuse and promote best practices and I didn't find a library which provided a simple and safe wrapper like this.

Scenario: Web application which has a data structure (e.g. a map) which is read and sometimes updated by multiple threads.

## Default solution:

```
var services = map[string]Service
var serviceMutex = sync.RWMutex{}

func UpdateValue(name, value Service) {
  serviceMutex.Lock()
  defer serviceMutex.Unlock()
  services[name] = value
}
```

## Possible misuses:

1. One could access the variable without locking the mutex (simple forget it)
2. One could write a long running method, accidentally locking the variable the whole time (because defer is only called after the whole method returns)
3. If the access is hidden behind Get/Set Methods one could accidentally write something like `v.Set(v.Get()+1)` and introduce a race condition.
4. One could accidentally pass a reference to the variable via return (allowing unlocked access).

## Solution: Library

You can play with the code and some example use-cases here: https://go.dev/play/p/-NCLyf3rh3g

### Code

```
// A wrapper for variables which are concurrently read/written by multiple go routines
// The value should be wrapped by New (or NewWithCopy) upon initialization and only
// be accessed by the methods in this package.
// RW.Read() and RW.Update() provide safe access and promote short-lived locks.
// RW.GetCopy() and RW.Set() are convenience implementations using Read/Update
// To use RW.GetCopy() provide a function to NewWithCopy() which creates a safe copy
// of the wrapped value ("safe" may depend on your use-case).
// This package provides default implementations for common cases as Copy*() Methods
package syncvar

import (
    "sync"
)

// RW will control Access to the wrapped value with a RWMutex
type RW[T any] struct {
    mutex sync.RWMutex
    value T
    copy  func(T) T
}

// New wraps value with a RWMutex. If you want to use the GetCopy method use NewWithCopy
func New[T any](value T) *RW[T] {
    return &RW[T]{
        mutex: sync.RWMutex{},
        value: value,
    }
}

// New wraps value with a RWMutex. The function copy is used by GetCopy
// and should create a concurrently safe copy of value T
// Implementations are provided for common types by the Copy* funcs in this package
func NewWithCopy[T any](value T, copy func(T) T) *RW[T] {
    return &RW[T]{
        mutex: sync.RWMutex{},
        value: value,
        copy:  copy,
    }
}

// Set will replace the value
func (s *RW[T]) Set(newValue T) {
    s.Update(func(orgValue *T) { *orgValue = newValue })
}

// GetCopy will provide a safe copy or panic if no copy function was defined by NewWithCopy
func (s *RW[T]) GetCopy() (value T) {
    if s.copy == nil {
        panic("no copy function provided (use syncvar.NewWithCopy)")
    }
    s.Read(func(orgValue T) { value = s.copy(orgValue) })
    return
}

// Read will read-lock the variable while executing f. f must not change the value
func (s *RW[T]) Read(f func(value T)) {
    s.mutex.RLock()
    defer s.mutex.RUnlock()
    f(s.value)
}

// Update will write-lock the variable while executing f
func (s *RW[T]) Update(f func(value *T)) {
    s.mutex.Lock()
    defer s.mutex.Unlock()
    f(&s.value)
}

// COPY HELPER FUNCTIONS

// CopyFlat uses a simple copy assignment for primitive values and structs
func CopyFlat[T comparable](original T) T { return original }

// CopyMap creates a shallow copy of all keys/values in the map
func CopyMap[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](original M) M {
    cp := M{}
    for k, v := range original {
        cp[k] = v
    }
    return cp
}

// CopySlice creates a shallow copy of the slice
func CopySlice[S ~[]T, T any](original S) S {
    cp := make(S, len(original))
    copy(cp, original)
    return cp
}

// CopyClonable uses the Clone() function of the value to create a copy
func CopyClonable[T Cloneable[T]](original T) T {
    return original.Clone()
}

type Cloneable[T any] interface {
    Clone() T
}
```

### GoDoc Usage Examples

```
package syncvar_test

import (
    "fmt"

    "gitlab.com/bfs-tools/service-orc/syncvar"
)

type config struct {
    path string
}

func ExampleRW_Read() {
    // initialization
    sv := syncvar.New(config{path: "test"})

    // A function using path
    var path string
    sv.Read(func(v config) { path = v.path })

    fmt.Print(path) // Output: test
}

func ExampleRW_Update() {
    // initialization
    sv := syncvar.New(config{path: "test"})

    // A function updating path
    sv.Update(func(v *config) { v.path = "new" })

    sv.Read(func(v config) { fmt.Print(v.path) })
    // Output: new
}

func ExampleRW_GetCopy() {
    // initialization
    sv := syncvar.NewWithCopy(
        map[string]string{"path": "test"},
        syncvar.CopyMap[map[string]string],
    )

    // m is a shallow copy of the wrapped value
    m := sv.GetCopy()
    m["path"] = "new"

    sv.Read(func(orgMap map[string]string) {
        fmt.Print(m["path"] + " - " + orgMap["path"])
    })
    // Output: new - test
}
```

## Thoughts:

I also code a lot of JavaScript, where lambda functions are used extensively (e.g. `doWithValue(value => {value.x = y})`. I think inline functions are a great fit for small bounded context operations like this. It is a clear visual boundary in the source code - and access to the variable is only allowed inside this function body.

How could this library code be improved? Is the idea of this package sound, or am I missing a simpler more effective option or even a standard package which solves this problems? I'm looking also for feedback on code-style, library-design and go best practices.